# Is there any analog of VB.NET's bitmap class for VB6?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a form and a custom scrollable PictureBox control (a very large PictureBox control inside another smaller PictureBox with 2 sliders to move large PictureBox inside smaller one). While scrolling large PictureBox inside smaller one the graphics that are drawn on large PictureBox get erased.

[image: an example of graphics get erased]

I would like to use a kind of off-screen buffer technique to cache all the drawing operations and to repaint the "dirty" parts of the view if necessary. There is [an example](http://www.visualbasicask.com/visual-basic-language/hscrollbar-autoredraw.shtml) of how to do this with [Bitmap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) in VB.NET.

Is there any analog of VB.NET's Bitmap class for Visual Basic 6?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it's possible to do what you want, but I believe all you are looking for is the AutoRedraw property of the picturebox.